# limit of $n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How can prove limit of $n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$ is 1 without using advanced theorem?

I think we have to make sequence which is greater than $n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$ and its limit is also 1 with just simple things (like $n^{\frac{1}{{n}}}$).

But it seems like impossible to me. :-(

-----edit-----

In this problem I can't use continuitiy or limit of function.

What I can use is just limit of sequence.

Comment: The standard approach would be to find the limit of the logarithm first.

Comment: Do you have to wear a blindfold while you solve it too?

Comment: This problem is from to the very first chapter of my analysis class. So I want to prove using just what I've learned in my class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $x^{1/x}\to1$ when $x\to\infty$, hence use the facts 
that $\sqrt{n}\to\infty$ and that
$$
n^{1/\sqrt{n}}=\left(\sqrt{n}^{1/\sqrt{n}}\right)^2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{n^{1/\sqrt{n}}}$.  We take the natural logarithm of both sides, and because the natural logarithm is continuous, the natural logarithm of the limit of the terms is the limit of the natural logarithm of the terms (assuming the terms are all positive, naturally).  Thus, 
$$\ln y=\ln \left[ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{n^{1/\sqrt{n}}}\right]=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\ln \left( n^{1/\sqrt{n}}\right)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

Now, it is a well-known fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{\ln n}{n^p}}=0$ for all $p>0$ (which follows from the dual fact for $e^x$), and thus the above limit is 0.  That is, $\ln y=0$, and thus we conclude that $y=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in this problem i can't use continuous property(but i know continuous). Is there any other solution with really simple theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to notice that $n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} = 2^{\frac{log_2(n)}{\sqrt n}}$.

Since $\frac{log_2(n)}{\sqrt n}\to 0$ and the exponent is a continuous function, $lim_{n\to \infty} 2^{\frac{log_2(n)}{\sqrt n}}=2^0=1.$

Comment: monotone >> continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n^{1/\sqrt{n}}=y$. Now, $\ln y=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ln n$. Then,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}y=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ln n\right)$$
Now, $\ln n$ grows much slower than $n^p$ for any $p>0$. Then, we may conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ln n=0$, i.e.,
$$\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}y=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/\sqrt{n}}=e^0=1}$$

Comment: You're "concluding" what you're trying to prove.

Comment: In this problem i can't use continuous property. Is there any other solution with really simple theorem?

Answer (score 0):

The general behavior of the function $f_n(x)=x^{x^n}$ on $(0,\infty)$ is determined completely by the sign of $n$ (assume $n\neq 0$).

If $n>0$, the graph descends from $1$ to a positive minimum somewhere between $x=0$ and $x=1$, then begins rising again, passing through $(1,1)$ and increasing to $\infty$.

If $n<0$, the graph ascends from $0$, passing through $(1,1)$ to a positive minimum greater than $1$ somewhere to the right of $x=1$, then descends asymptotically down towards $1$.

So in your case, $n=-\frac12$, and we are in the second case. The limiting value is $1$, and in fact the sequence has a strictly decreasing tail (this is true in the general case for negative $n$).

The location and value of the extremum is easily computed if desired.

Comment: Can you give a proof of this claim (undoubtedly true) without using continuity arguments, as the OP has required?

Comment: @Hayden: Not easily. But that requirement was added to the question in a later edit.